# Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland"

Tags: python, opencv, artificial-intelligence

```
import cv2
trained_face_data = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
img = cv2.imread('John.jpeg')
grayscaled_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
face_coordinates = trained_face_data.detectMultiScale(grayscaled_img)
print(face_coordinates)
cv2.rectangle(grayscaled_img, (961, 559), (961+2575, 559+2575), (0,255,0), 2)
cv2.imshow('000',grayscaled_img)
cv2.waitKey()
print("Code Completed")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFI3p.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T1ZN.png)
I kept getting the error:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in
"/home/ewen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins"
```

I think it is because of `cv2.imshow('000',grayscaled_img)`

Also, I don't know if it is because of the error but my image doesn't have the green square that show the character's face

I don't know where is the problem , I follow the tutorial video but it doesn't get any errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWcHA.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Please share your code as text and not as image. Also you should provide a minimal reproducable example.

Comment: This is apparently a known issue -- opencv python bindings ship with their own QT build which does not ship with wayland plugin.  See; https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/729

Comment: If you see the display image, then you can ignore the error message, it is not related to your problem.

Comment: Happy that you found your solution. Normally we'd like you to self-answer it but for now, could you edit your solution into your question itself? You can always make it a proper answer later with enough reputation. See: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)